# Creating documentation with mkdocs

Tags: documentation

I am using mkdocs for making my documentation file. Its really awesome to make docs with it since it is a static site generator. My doubt is can we create documentation with mkdocs like phpdocumentor? That means just by parsing through the comments and creates docs? Is it possible with mkdocs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible I'm afraid. MkDocs is a python static site generator while phpdocumentor is a php parser. You could probably create a theme for phpdocumentor based upon one of the themes provided by mkdocs.